# Login Template for django-social-auth

Tags: django, authentication, django-registration, django-socialauth

I have successfully installed django-social-auth. I entered the API keys and it is even working. But now I do not know how to create a login template where I can provide both social login as well as traditional registration.

I have the links for social auth for twitter, facebook etc But I do not know how to create a form for a registration to create a django user. Can anybody please help me. I am a beginner in handling Django templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First result in google for "django registration user" query search :

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/sep/02/django-tips-user-registration/

You could make the search on your own.

By the way, this article is fairly good :)

Comment: Actually You did not get my question, I already know what you have sent me. But I a using django-social-auth which provides us both social registration as well as creating new django users. So i was thinking how can I make use of what is already built by django-social-auth

Comment: @Sachin Yeah I don't really understand your question. Do you need help in the creation of the template which will display the form ?
Another thing is : you want registration OR authentication ? sign-in or sign-up ?

Comment: I want to give the option that user can either authenticate using social login, or create one's own account on django. I want to create a form where they can either sign in using social registration or sign up by creating their own account. I hope i am clearer now?

Comment: so you just want to add a <a> link tag after that has been built by django-social-auth redirecting to a view where the user can sign up ?
And this view will simply contain a django user form ?

Comment: Oh! It means I was mistaken I thought that social-auth provides this registration also... It is clear now thanks